# Solve ordinary differential equations using SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I have a following 
[ordinary differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RcuQ.png)
and numeric parameters [Sigma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ol8B.png)=0.4, x(0) = 4 and dx(0)/dt = 0
My task is to get Cauchy problem solution (Initial value problem solution) of differential equation using `ode` function
Can someone help me? I don't even know how to write equation and especially numeric parameters in correct way for SciPy.

 P.S. Sorry for not posting images, I've just registered.

Comment: This differential equation doesn't look partial to me.

Comment: You have an [*ordinary* differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) with initial values specified at t=0.  That is not a partial differential equation.  I don't know what you mean by "partial solution".  By the way, your equation is linear with constant coefficients.  An exact solution can be derived.  Do you really have to use scipy?

Comment: @jacques-de-hooge I know that this is ordinary differential equation. Sorry for mistranslating.

Comment: Have you seen the example in the [docstring for `scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)?

Comment: @warren-weckesser I found a correct term for this: Cauchy problem solution (Also known as initial value problem).
I need to use SciPy to get a solution of Cauchy problem for this differential equation.

Comment: @warren-weckesser I saw it, looks like my situation, but I didn't manage to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Warren said, scipy.integrate.odeint is the 'SciPy' way to solve this.

But before you take your problem to SciPy (or whatever solver you end up using) you'll want to convert your 2nd order ODE to a first order ODE using something like: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx

To get things into SciPy you need to get your equation looking like:

y' = f(y)

But right now your equation is written like:

y'' = f(y, y')

The solution is to add more variables to your system, but the link will explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and say you result

Comment: Actually [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) article contains all information needed.